# How to maintain the scroll position when adding elements to the top and bottom of a container in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to replicate infinite-scroll in React. The problem statement is,

1. To load new elements whenever the user reaches the bottom of the container
2. At a particular time not more than 10 elements should be in the container (for render performance)
3. So when we scroll up the same thing should happen, i.e previous elements should load when we scroll to the top.

I have been able to achieve most of it but the only thing that I am stuck at is that when I scroll to the top and the component prepends previous elements to the list, the scroll position is stuck at the top, which is not the desired effect that I want.

**How to maintain the scroll position when adding elements to the top and bottom of a container in React?**

NOTE: It is not happening when I scroll to the bottom. When I scroll to the bottom the new elements are rendered below the bottommost element, so the scroll posistion goes to the half of the list and I can scroll to the bottom again.

NOTE 2: This was happening when scrolling to the bottom as well but it got solved when I changed the key to what I got from the api (unique key) instead of using the index from map function. My guess is that React remembers that this element (let key=k) was present before updating the component and when it re-rendered the DOM, it sets the scroll position to that of the element with key=k. But why is it not happening for top elements, I can't figure out.

CODE
Constants.pageSize is 5
And sendQuery returns an array having Constants.pageSize number of elements from the provided page number.

EDIT: CodeSandBox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/infinite-scroll-ip9ggz?file=/src/components/contianer.js

```js
const Container = () => {
    const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1)
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const lastElemRef = useRef(null)
    const firstElemRef = useRef(null)
    const isFirstRender = useFirstRender()
    const pageNumberRef = useRef(pageNumber)

    useEffect(() => {
        if(pageNumberRef.current < pageNumber){ // next page
            sendQuery(pageNumber).then((res) => {
                const prevData = data.slice(-Constants.pageSize)
                setData([...prevData, ...res])
                
            })
        }
        else{
            sendQuery(pageNumber-1).then((res) => {
                const prevData = data.slice(0, Constants.pageSize)
                setData([...res, ...prevData])
            })
        }
        pageNumberRef.current = pageNumber
    }, [pageNumber])

    const callBack = useCallback((entries) => {
        const target = entries[0]
            if(target.target.id === "load-next" && target.isIntersecting && !isFirstRender){
                setPageNumber(page => page + 1)
            }

            if(target.target.id === "load-prev" && target.isIntersecting && !isFirstRender){
                setPageNumber(page => {
                    if(page > 2){
                        return page-1
                    }else{
                        return page
                    }
                })
            }
    }, [isFirstRender, setPageNumber])

    useEffect(() => {
        observer = new IntersectionObserver(callBack, {root: document.getElementById("container"), threshold: 0.5})

        const lastElem = lastElemRef.current
        const firstElem = firstElemRef.current
        if(lastElem){
            observer.observe(lastElem)
            observer.observe(firstElem)
        }
        return (() => {
            if(lastElem){
                observer.unobserve(lastElem)
                observer.observe(firstElem)
            }
        })
    }, [callBack])

    return (
        <div id="container" className="container">
            <div ref={firstElemRef} id="load-prev"></div>
            {
                data.map((post, index) => {
                    return (
                        <Post 
                            image={post.urls.regular} 
                            by={post.user.first_name} 
                            key={post.id}
                        />
                    )
                })
            }
            <div ref={lastElemRef} style={{height: "300px"}} id="load-next"></div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is usually solved by libraries -- which are quite complex and theirs no need to reinvent the wheel. Try https://tanstack.com/virtual/v3 or https://react-window.vercel.app/.

The way these libraries solve this issue is even for the off-screen rows, space is still accounted for them by manually setting the height of the inner container above and below the sliding window.

You could replicate it by passing the count of the items, and setting the height of the container based on this, then playing with the padding in the inner container to compensate for the unrendered items.

But yes, this is actually quite complex to do -- you would almost always lean on a well maintained open source lib for this unless theres a really compelling reason not to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Adam. I wanted to learn React by creating this project, and I thought if it is able to handle the downward scroll then it should be able to handle the upward scroll too. I thought I was missing something. I still think there should be a better way to handle this and I'll try to attach a code sandbox for people to correctly understand the problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have added the sandbox link in the question

Comment: The reason upwards does not work is since when you reinsert an item at the top, it pushes the other content down -- which changes the perceived scroll position. When you scroll to the bottom, there is no other content to push down. The only way to fix this is the technique described - you need to add padding above the rendered items to compensate for the non-rendered ones. Its complex, as you basically need consistent height items where that height is known before render - which is a common restriction of virtualisation libs like the ones linked. It is almost notoriously annoying to implement.